# View Stack Overflow's Developer profile/data for yourself

Tags: support, personal-data

I remember there used to be a way to download the data that Stack Overflow had stored on me. Is this still accessible? If so, where can I go to download it?

Comment: Did you mean the one on the [Preferences - Activity data](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current)?

Comment: Or did you mean a full [GDPR data request](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/gdpr/request)?

Comment: I was thinking of the preferences and activity data however, the gdpr link is also useful, thank you both for your help.